# see more/see less to disable still not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

hope you are all safe and well.

Have inherited a SaaS/web based 'design online' website, and it runs okay for our small business, before I have plans for a full Magento2 build, however there is a 'show more/show less' function I would like to get rid of on the product pages. See here, for example:

https://black-rhodium.co.uk/Products#!/products/bolero-s

can drop blocks of code in, but don't have an option in the back end of the web based site builder to turn this 'see more/see less' feature on and off.

Can any of you guys help me with a snippet of code to force it to disappear, so I just have the block of text for the product description to display as normal in full, on page load?

have already tried the below, to no avail

```
<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide {display: none;}">Show more</div>
<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide {display: none;}">Show less</div>
```

Have also tried !important and 1/0/0/0 on the above, and that hasn't worked either.

Have placed in body, body2, head, footer, none has worked.

can delete this in opera inspector, to give me the result I want, with the entire product description there:

```
<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide focus">Show less</div>
```

Although, nothing I add will essentially override it.

someone could help me out, that would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fully understand.. do you want to hide

`<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide">Show more</div>`

and

`<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide">Show less</div>`

using CSS?

if so, try,

`<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide" style="display: none">Show more</div>` same for the `show less` one.

Other CSS alternatives would be:

`width: 0; height: 0;`

`visibility: hidden;`

`opacity: 0;`

But I think that in your case you'll have to remove the function from the backend.

Comment: Hi Patrick, any language is fine for a solution. I essentially just want the entire product description to show on page load, without clicking 'show more'/'show less' which I can't seem to disable.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for this, but neither has worked.

Comment: Do you know the name of the function?

Comment: And what happens when you remove it?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I can remove it in inspector on a browser, which is this part: <div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide focus">Show less</div> however, I can't remove or override this function by adding a snippet of code.

Comment: Okay yeah, I just saw that's all CSS. Can't you edit the CSS? Remove the overflow: hidden; and so on

Comment: Hi Patrick, I can't - this is a drag and drop system. I can however, add blocks of code. I was hoping to add some code to override it.

Comment: Do you mean a block of code that changes multiply div's CSS? Could it be written in Javascript?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I believe I can add HTML, CSS and Javascript using the online editor.

Comment: You can use `style` property to override your CSS.  The snippet would look like this `document.getElementsByClassName('className').style = your_style`

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for this. It still hasn't worked. I'm about ready to pull my hair out.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be built out. What drag and drop system are you using?

Comment: Before I look at it, isn't there support that could help you on one.com? Perhaps you just pop them a message and ask for help and possible ways of solving your problem.

Comment: Hi Patrick, already tried. They raised a ticket a fortnight ago, haven't heard anything since, and I've asked again too.

Comment: Going to take a look just now

Comment: Okay, yeah I think you need to wait for an answer from them.. there's no information about custom CSS styling.

Comment: Hi Patrick, shall see what they say. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Patrick, have finally heard back, there is nothing they can do.